# "dims [product 0] do not match the length of object" error in R when using daply for frequency counts

Tags: r, dataframe, plyr, frequency

I have a list of data.frames that looks like this:

```
df=data.frame(
data_id=rep(LETTERS[1:10],each=1),
data_value=c(1,2,2,3,3,2,3,1,1,3))
df2=data.frame(
data_id=rep(LETTERS[1:10],each=1),
data_value=c(2,1,3,1,1,1,2,1,2,1))
df3=data.frame(
data_id=rep(LETTERS[1:10],each=1),
data_value=c(2,2,3,3,1,2,2,1,2,3))
df.list <- list(df, df2, df3)
```

A single data.frame looks like this:

```
         data_id    data_value
1        A          1
2        B          2
3        C          2
4        D          3
5        E          3
6        F          2
7        G          3
8        H          1
9        I          1
10       J          3
```

I want to have a frequency count of how often each unique value appears in data_value. I can do this:

```
for(i in 1:length(df.list)){
    daply(df.list[[i]], .(df.list[[i]]$data_value), nrow) -> freq
}
```

Which gives me the frequency count (in this case just the last one, for df3):

```
1 2 3 
2 5 3
```

My actual dataset is far bigger so I cannot post it here. It has the exact same structure, however. The problem is that when I try to get the frequency counts for my actual dataset, I get the following error message:

```
Error in dim(out_array) <- out_dim : dims [product 0] do not match the length of object [1]
```

Can anyone tell me where I need to start looking to fix this? I don't understand where 'dim()' comes in and what it does. Many thanks.

Comment: It is difficult to tell the reason without having the data.set on which this error is produced. Please provide a reproducible example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can actually do one better than that, by replacing the for-loop with a `laply`, which means input is a list and output is a matrix/array.

```
o <- laply(df.list, function(x) {
    table(x$data_value)
})
> o
#      1 2 3
# [1,] 3 3 4
# [2,] 6 3 1
# [3,] 2 5 3
```

In order to check the reason for your error, what happens when you try this?

```
o <- llply(df.list, function(x) {
    table(x$data_value)
})
```

**Edit:** To make the error more understandable, let us create this data.frame:

```
d1 <- data.frame(a=1:4)
d2 <- data.frame(a=1:5)
d3 <- data.frame(a=1:6)
d4 <- data.frame(a=1:7)

dl <- list(d1,d2,d3,d4)
```

Now run `laply`:

```
laply(dl, function(x) table(x$a))
# Error: Results must have the same dimensions.
```

why? To see that, let's print it:

```
> laply(dl, function(x) print(table(x$a)))

# 1 2 3 4 
# 1 1 1 1 
# 
# 1 2 3 4 5 
# 1 1 1 1 1 
# 
# 1 2 3 4 5 6 
# 1 1 1 1 1 1 
# 
# 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 
# 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 

# Error: Results must have the same dimensions.
```

You see the problem? The number of elements in each row are different. You can NOT have a matrix (unless you append those with smaller elements to equal the rows).

Instead, use a list so that they will be elements of a list which can be accessed later using `[[number]]` syntax.

```
llply(dl, function(x) table(x$a))

# [[1]]
# 
# 1 2 3 4 
# 1 1 1 1 
# 
# [[2]]
# 
# 1 2 3 4 5 
# 1 1 1 1 1 
# 
# [[3]]
# 
# 1 2 3 4 5 6 
# 1 1 1 1 1 1 
# 
# [[4]]
# 
# 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 
# 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

Hope this clears things up.

Comment: Thanks Arun! What happens for your first option with laply() is the following error message: Error: Results must have the same dimensions. Your second option with llply produces a list of tables with the required frequency tables! Thanks!

Comment: Maybe the issue with daply() and laply() is that not all data.frames included the list have the same dimensions (column numbers are all the same, but row numbers vary)?

Comment: Yes, that is because a matrix should always have same amount of rows/cols. But there are cases in your actual data that this is violated. Probably there are some data.frames where there are only 2 unique values, and some with 3 unique values.. etc.. check that. (I'll edit to make this comment more understandable)

Comment: I understand it completely. Stupid mistake, because I would have found out if I had used data.frames with different row lengths for the example dataset. I left out the critical feature which caused the problem. Thank you for explaining!